# Prove that $\sup(S-T)=\sup S-\inf T$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets of real numbers and define
>   $$S-T=\{s-t|s\in S,t\in T\}$$
>   Show that if S and T are bounded then
>   $$\sup(S-T)=\sup S-\inf T\\
> \inf(S-T)=\inf S-\sup T.$$

*My proof:*

Since $S,T\subset\mathbb{R}$ are nonempty and bounded, then, by the Completeness Axiom, we have $\alpha=\sup S,\beta=\inf T$. Let $m\in S-T$ so that $m=s-t\leq\alpha-\beta\,$ which implies that $S-T$ is bounded above so a supremum exists: denote $\gamma=\sup(S-T)\leq\alpha-\beta$. By a theorem stated in my book, pick any $\epsilon>0$, then $\exists x\in S, \exists y\in T$ such that $$(1)\,\alpha-\epsilon<x,\quad\quad(2)\,y<\beta+\epsilon\equiv-\beta-\epsilon<-y.$$
And by adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
$$\alpha-\beta-2\epsilon\leq\alpha-\beta<x-y$$
Given that $x-y\in S-T$ then 
$$\alpha-\beta<x-y\leq\gamma.$$
Since $\gamma\leq\alpha-\beta$ and $\alpha-\beta\leq \gamma$ we have that $\gamma=\alpha-\beta$.
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\square$$

Would this work?

Comment: Could you explain how you got $$\alpha-\epsilon<\alpha+y-\beta<x?$$

Comment: @TheoBendit By inequality $(2)$ we have that $\epsilon>y-\beta$ and using $(1)$ we have that $\alpha-\epsilon<\alpha+y-\beta$. Would this implication be correct?

Comment: Surely $-\epsilon < \beta - y$, so $\alpha - \epsilon < \alpha + \beta - y$?

Comment: It seems a correct implication to me...

Comment: But I got something different from you. I don't think yours is correct.

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $x$ and $y$ such that $\alpha - \varepsilon < x \le \alpha$ and $-\beta - \varepsilon < -y \le -\beta$. Choosing such $x$ and $y$ represent a small concession: you know that $\alpha$ and $-\beta$ may not be achievable, but you know that you can get as close as you want to these bounds, and you're happy to concede $\varepsilon$ distance from these ideals. That's why you're not going to be able to cancel these $\varepsilon$s: you can't make two of these concessions, and expect anything except that these concessions will add to each other.

Instead, observe that,
$$\alpha - \beta - 2 \varepsilon < x - y \le \alpha - \beta.$$
It follows that
$$\alpha - \beta - 2\varepsilon < \sup (A - B) \le \alpha - \beta.$$
But, there is only one number that satisfies this for any $\varepsilon > 0$. We must have
$$\sup (A - B) = \alpha - \beta.$$

Answer (score 1):

From (2) we get $-\epsilon<\beta-y$, so $\alpha-\epsilon<\alpha+\beta-y$. The proof needs a little work, but you can salvage it. You don't need to use (1).

Also, we have $\alpha-\epsilon<x$ and $\alpha-\epsilon<\alpha+\beta-y$. This doesn't tell us $\alpha+\beta-y<x$, but we don't need that anyways.

Comment: $\alpha+\beta-y<x$ doesn't help me at all because my goal is to show that $\gamma\leq\alpha-\beta$ and $\alpha-\beta\leq\gamma$ implies thaat $\gamma=\alpha-\beta$

Comment: You used it in your derivation of $\alpha-\beta<x-y$.

Comment: Is my correction valid now?

Comment: When you write $\alpha-\beta-2\epsilon\leq\alpha-\beta<x-y$, I don't think that follows. This would lead to a contradiction, for $\gamma\leq\alpha-\beta$ and $\gamma>\alpha-\beta$. By trichotomy this cannot happen.

You can just use that $\alpha-\beta-2\epsilon<x-y$, therefore $\alpha-\beta\leq x-y$. This leads to your desired result.

Comment: $\alpha-\beta-2\epsilon<x-y\leq\gamma\implies \alpha-\beta<\gamma+2\epsilon$ which holds for every $\epsilon>0$ so $\alpha-\beta\leq \gamma$

Comment: Consider $\gamma<\gamma+2\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, but $\gamma\not<\gamma$. The inequality is not strict. This implies $\alpha-\beta\leq\gamma$.